# sql server ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout

I am using a multithreaded application to extract data from a database and after a few minutes of running I start to get this exception or an sql timeout exception.  My code is below:

```
    public static List<FlightInfo> FlightInfoAllPricesPerDayForRoute(string From, string To)
    { // Create the object array from the datareader
        List<FlightInfo> arr = new List<FlightInfo>();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("FlightInfoAllPricesPerDayForRoute", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
            {
                conn.Open(); command.CommandTimeout = 150;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AirportFrom", From);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AirportTo", To);
                // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date",  dt);


                //execute the stored procedure
                using (IDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {


                    FlightInfo obj;

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        obj = new FlightInfo();
                        obj.flightInfoID = (int)dr["FlightInfoID"];
                        obj.airportFrom = (string)dr["AirportFrom"];
                        obj.airportTo = (string)dr["AirportTo"];
                        obj.timeDeparture = DateTime.Parse(dr["TimeDeparture"].ToString());
                        obj.timeArrival = (DateTime)dr["TimeArrival"];
                        obj.price = (short)Int16.Parse(dr["Price"].ToString());
                        obj.dateAdded = (DateTime)dr["DateAdded"];
                        obj.carrier = (string)dr["Carrier"];

                        arr.Add(obj);
                    }

                    dr.Close(); dr.Dispose(); conn.Close(); conn.Dispose(); command.Dispose();


                }
            }
        } return arr;
    }
```

I have added teh following to the connection string to improve the timeout problem but am still getting errors:

```
   Min Pool Size=200;Max Pool Size=32767;Asynchronous Processing=true;   Connect Timeout=150;
```

The stored procedure is very simple so I don't think there is a problem there:

```
select *,  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TimeDeparture)) as FlightDate
from FlightInfo  
where AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and AirportTo = @AirportTo
AND TimeDeparture > GETDATE() -- Only get future flights
Order by FlightDate ASC, Price asc
```

I've also tried running this to check the sql connections but I get a 'The user does not have permission to perform this action.' error

```
  SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok - I suggest you look on the database server for your problem. If the stored proc takes a long time to run and/or causes a lot of locking in the tables, you could get these problems (especially if it is called frequently). Some query optimization is probably in order.

fyi - you don't need a 'using' block around a SqlCommand object. Also, there is no need to call 'close' and 'dispose' on your reader and connection objects - the 'using' will handle that for you.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the limits on SQL server as I get this error on multiple stored procedures, not just this one?  I've added my SP to the question.

Comment: 'Increasing the limits' would be a last resort. Finding the bottleneck is what you need to do. Even if the stored proc is simple, if it is accessing a large table without a proper index, it could still take a long time. If there are a lot of concurrent users, especially if they are updating the table, the procedure could be blocked. One of the other procedures could be causing the problem.

Comment: The application is extracting and analysing data offline (it's not driving a website or anything like that).  There is another application adding data into the db but this is at a rate of 100 inserts/min and some of the other procedures take around 5 seconds to run as the db has around 20 million records.  The table has been indexed as best that I know how to and data access speed seems to be ok now.  I have reduced the number of concurrent threads in the application to 10 which has helped.  Is there a way to monitor the sql connections to see where most of them are coming from?

Comment: The simplest way is to use the activity monitor in ssms. It shows a lot of info on who is connected and what they are doing. The 'recent expensive queries' panel is vey helpful. There are also commercial tools that can help with this, as well as dynamic management views you can use to get more info. I don't personally have a lot of experience with these, so I can't recommend anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem when running the SP with certain parameters because there was a problem with the code inserting into the database meaning that many duplicate entries were added in certain circumstances.  When I was trying to extract data from the database using parameters that had many duplicate db entries the SP ran very slowly.  Removing these duplicates improved the problem.